# How to use Convert.ToDateTime in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a question about EntityFrameWork/LINQ.
First, I want to set Year from b.Datetime(data type is string), so I use Convert.ToDateTime method, but an error occurs.

Here is my code.

```cs
IQueryable<AlarmCount> alarmCount = from b in fatalalarminfo
                                    group b by new
                                    {
                                        GroupKey = b.Eqpid,
                                        Year = Convert.ToDateTime(b.DateTime).Year
                                     } into gbs
                                     orderby gbs.Key.Year, gbs.Key.GroupKey
                                     select new AlarmCount()
                                     {
                                         GroupKey = gbs.Key.GroupKey,
                                         Period = new Period(EnumPeriodType.YEAR, gbs.Key.Year),
                                         Amount = gbs.Count()
                                     };
```

See the error message below.

[image]

Comment: You mean `b.DateTime` column in the database stores value in string?

Comment: Right! "character varying"

Comment: Not all C# methods can be translated to SQL functions in EF. Hence there is no direct solution for this. You can get the year from the string column value using `Substring`. the best solution will be to use DateTime column in the database table. This will save you many such problems in future.

Comment: Did you try to cast to DateTime? EF could call the SQL function cast? `(DateTime)(object)b.DateTime` ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that it is an IQueryable.
This means that your linq query is being translated to SQL, and it cannot translate Convert.ToDateTime to sql.
You can use `DateTime.ParseExact`, which does translate to SQL properly.

```
IQueryable<AlarmCount> alarmCount = from b in fatalalarminfo
                                            group b by new
                                            {
                                                GroupKey = b.Eqpid,
                                                Year = DateTime.ParseExact(b.DateTime, "<format>", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Year
                                            } into gbs
                                            orderby gbs.Key.Year, gbs.Key.GroupKey
                                            select new AlarmCount()
                                            {
                                                GroupKey = gbs.Key.GroupKey,
                                                Period = new Period(EnumPeriodType.YEAR, gbs.Key.Year),
                                                Amount = gbs.Count()
                                            };
```

Make sure to replace `<format>` with the correct format.

Comment: thanks for your opinion. but the same error is occurred...ㅠㅠ
Message : Translation of method 'System.DateTime.ParseExact' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function

Comment: If all the dates are in the same format, you can try to use substring to get the year, however it is not a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `IQueryable<T>` does queries in database, you get this exception because there is no function mapped to `Convert.ToDateTime` in your database. Try `IEnumerable<T>` instead.